# Draw Borders in Print Preview but the Borders Should not Print C#

Tags: c#, .net, image, winforms, printing

I'm using WinForms. In my Form i have a picturebox and a button that prints the pictures in the picturebox.

In my code when you click on the print button the program displays a print preview with a rectangular box around the image. I drew this rectangular box because I have specific kinds of papers that i print to. These papers have pictures on the borders. The users cant print over the pictures on the paper. I just want to inform the users that if you pass these rectangular borderlines in the print preview that you will be printing on top of the pictures on the paper.

Goal: When i click on the print button I want to see a print-preview paper with a rectangular border, but i don't want the rectangular boarder to print. I just want the image to print.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
        printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        var bmp = new Bitmap(this.pictureBox1.Width, this.pictureBox1.Height);
        this.pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, this.pictureBox1.ClientRectangle);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Salmon, 25, 25, 500, 1000);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 25, 25, 500, 500); //Gets the input from the textboxes
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Create a boolean variable called "drawBorder" that is true when you click on the preview button.

Comment: I'm going to try that @LarsTech

Comment: @taji01 Be sure to reset it back to false when the print button is clicked.

Comment: I'm kinda lost, but something like this, bool drawBorder = false;  and in preview_button_click{ drawBorder = true} @RonBeyer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [PrintController.IsPreview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printcontroller.ispreview(v=vs.110).aspx) property for that:

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    var bmp = new Bitmap(this.pictureBox1.Width, this.pictureBox1.Height);
    this.pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, this.pictureBox1.ClientRectangle);
    if (this.printDocument1.PrintController.IsPreview) {
      e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Salmon, 25, 25, 500, 1000);
    }
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 25, 25, 500, 500); //Gets the input from the textboxes
}
```

Comment: It still prints with those border lines @LarsTech

Comment: @taji01 If the PictureBox has a painted border, then that would have to be removed.

Comment: I added a picture on my question to let you see a visual, because i don't think i added some sort of border into it

Comment: @taji01 No, the visual doesn't help since I don't see a border.  But clearly from the code, the border only gets drawn when drawBorder is true.  Try commenting out the DrawRectangle and see if you get a border.  If you do, it's coming from somewhere else.

Comment: When I commented out the------------ if (drawBorder)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Salmon, 25, 25, 500, 1000);
            } --------- i don't get the border in the print preview

Comment: @taji01 You are confusing me.  My understanding is you want the border in the preview, but not the printer.  If you want the border, drawBorder = true, if not, then drawBorder = false.  That variable needs to be set before running your print function.

Comment: Yes i do want the border in the preview. I wan't the users to see the border, but I don't want the border printed out with the image. The image should only print out when i click on the print button in the print preview section.

Comment: @taji01 Ah, now I understand.  Try `if (this.printDocument1.PrintController.IsPreview) {...` instead.  I didn't test this.

Comment: I'll try this and let you know :)